# Full Height Sidebar With Footer in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to have a full height sidebar (see #left in example), while still having a footer, using the bootstrap framework.

[View the fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ycmfe97z/7/)

I've tried the following, but it is not 'footer friendly'.  The goal is to have the sidebar 100% of the page height.

```
#left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set `display: flex;` on the row, for viewport width greater than 992px

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row {
      display: flex;
  }
}
```

### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ycmfe97z/10/)

**NB:** This can ruin other parts of the layout, so if need be - you can make the selector more specific in order to select only that row that you want to be full height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body {
      overflow: hidden;
}    

#left {
      background-color: #aaa;
      padding-bottom: 99999px;
      margin-bottom: -99999px;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Use a wrapper (ex: `<div class="wrapper"></div>` css for it `.wrapper { overflow: hidden; }`) or some another class/id and use overflow:hidden style for it.

Answer (score 0):

I might have another way of thinking. Bootstrap have classes that is set rows and col.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Try exploring the right class number for your webpage to be a responsive website. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. The code you used is perfectly alright.

**Updated:**

```
#left {
    position: absolute; //changed from fixed
    top: 51px;
    left: 0; // removed bottom:0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: pink;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

You just need to do couple of small changes to others to get the desired results from here. Assuming when you said 100%, you meant excluding the top navbar.

1) You just need to push the `id="main"` div to the right using `float: right;` so it fits the layout and not hide behind the `#left` sidebar. Like so

```
#mid {
  float: right; //added
  background: #666;
}
```

2) For your footer problem, the culprit is the placement of the `<footer>` section. If you want the sidebar to extend to full height, even besides the footer. You should place it inside the `#main` div below the contents.

[Latest Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycmfe97z/12/).

Comment: This is close to what I was thinking, and I believe I was able to get to th is point before.  However, i imagined the footer being under the sidebar, if possible.

Comment: If i got your requirement right, you need footer below sidebar + the sidebar should extend to the full height between header and footer. If so all you need is to **place the footer just after `#main` div** and change the `#left` new styles to the one I updated in the answer. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycmfe97z/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS but there are drawbacks for that solution. And Flexbox still has browser compatibility issues.

There is a simple solution to this using jQuery. You just have to write few lines of codes.

Create a function first:

```
function sidebarHeight() {
  var containerHeight = $('.main-content').height();
  $('.sidebar').height(containerHeight);
}
```

Then run that functions on page load and browser resize.

```
$(window).load(sidebarHeight);
$(window).resize(sidebarHeight);
```

If you want to read full details, I wrote a tutorial on my [Blog](http://andwecode.com/full-height-sidebar-jquery/).
Here is the demo on [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/monkeytempal/pen/bpMJWo).

Answer (score -2):

Try doing `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`.